# -phobia (or similar) word for "fear of the poor"

Tags: finance, phobias, sociolinguistics

*Peniaphobia* seems to refer at least as much to the *fear or hatred of being or becoming poor oneself*, as it refers to *fear or hatred of people who are already poor*.

What would be a good word, or concise term, for the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aporophobia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aporophobia)
1. (rare) A strong antipathy, aversion or hatred toward poverty or poor people.

See also:

> For something to exist in collective consciousness we must be able to name it. Naming what happens and not seeing or not wanting to see is what philosopher Adela Cortina has done with a reality that is re but we prefer to ignore: fear, aversion and rejection of poor. It has been called aporofobia, a phenomenon that is at origin of currents of xenophobia and racism that extend through affluent western world. Adela Cortina coined this concept from terms Grietos Greek áporos (without resources) and Phobos (fear, panic) and it has used it in academic works and articles, until imposing it, despite reticence of editors with strange words, like title of its Last book: Aporofobia, rejection of poor (Paidós, 2017). The effort has been rewarded. A few weeks ago neologism was incorporated into dictionary of Spanish Language and foundation of Spanish urgent has declared word of year 2017, as in previous years were populism, refugee, Selfi and Escrache. In word aporofobia Fundéu has found not only a very significant term, but a rare linguistic avis: "A voice with known author and date of birth".
>   ("[Aporofobia](http://www.turkeytelegraph.com/business/aporofobia-the-fear-of-the-poor-who-nullifies-empathy-h14799.html), the fear of the poor who nullifies empathy" -- Fundéu declares word of the year 2017 the term coined by the philosopher Adela Cortina, Turkey Telegraph, 04 January 2018 Thursday, 12:00)